# How can I limit AWS Cognito access to ADFS users of a certain group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, adfs

I have an application that I want both Cognito User pool users and ADFS users to access. However the ADFS users have to be part of a certain group(s) to access the app. How can I enforce this restriction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you would have created a Relying Party for AWS congnito within ADFS for the access and application configuration within your Identity provider (which is ADFS in this case) . You would need to find the SID of the group and manually modify the claim rules in order to restrict this access.  You can use the powershell on your local Active Directory server to get the SID of the group you want to allow for access.

Get-ADGroup -Identity "Name of your group"

And then you would need to use the following line to include within your existing claim rule.

&& exists([Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid", Value =~ ""])

exists([Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid", Value== "", Issuer =~ "^AD AUTHORITY$"]) => issue(Type ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit", Value ="true");

The above two are examples and you can use any of the two as per your relying party configurations on ADFS .

Comment: Thanks Shashi, I have the following claim rule added:

`c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid", Value == "MY SID", Issuer =~ "^AD AUTHORITY$"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit", Value = "true");
`
However all users are still authenticated through ADFS, is there something I am missing in order to fully deny entry to users not in the group?